# Error: "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field"

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, error, sobject

I'm getting this error while running this VF Page

> Error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Task.LastModifiedById
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="task" extensions="TaskHistoryController">
  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageMessages escape="false"/> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

Contrloller:

```
public with sharing class TaskHistoryController {



Task objTask;
String objTaskId;

public TaskHistoryController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    objTask = (Task)controller.getRecord();
    Id taskId = objTask.Id;
    List<Task_Activity_History__c> listTaskActivityHistory = [SELECT Field_Name__c, Id, Old_Value__c, New_Value__c, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate FROM Task_Activity_History__c WHERE Task_ID__c = :taskId]; 
    Task_Activity_History__c taskHistory1 = listTaskActivityHistory.get(0);
    Task_Activity_History__c taskHistory2 = listTaskActivityHistory.get(1);
    String newValue1 = taskHistory1.New_Value__c;
    String newValue2 = taskHistory2.New_Value__c;
    String resultAll = buildTemplate(objTask);
    ApexPages.Message infoPage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, resultAll);
    ApexPages.addMessage(infoPage);
}

public String buildTemplate(Task task) {
    Id lastModifiedBy = task.LastModifiedById;
    String userName = '';
    List<User> listOfUsers = [SELECT Id, IsActive, LastModifiedById, Name FROM User where Id = :lastModifiedBy];
    for(User user :listOfUsers) {
        userName = user.Name;
    }
    Id taskId = task.Id;
    List<Task_Activity_History__c> listTaskActivityHistory = [SELECT Field_Name__c, Id, Old_Value__c, New_Value__c, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate FROM Task_Activity_History__c WHERE Task_ID__c = :taskId];
    String pageHTMLContent = '<HTML><HEAD><STYLE>table.user_class, .user_class th, .user_class td { border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; } table.user_class th { text-align: center; } </STYLE></HEAD><BODY><TABLE class="user_class">';
    pageHTMLContent += '<TR><TH>Comment Old Value</TH><TH>Comment New Value</TH><TH>Last Modified By</TH><TH>Last Modified Date</TH>';
    for(Task_Activity_History__c taskActivityHistory :listTaskActivityHistory) {
        String newValue1 = taskActivityHistory.Old_Value__c;
        String newValue2 = taskActivityHistory.New_Value__c;
        String lastModifiedById = taskActivityHistory.LastModifiedById;
        DateTime lastModifiedByDate = taskActivityHistory.LastModifiedDate;
        pageHTMLContent += '<TR>';
        pageHTMLContent += '<TD>' + newValue1 + '</TD><TD>' + newValue2 + '</TD><TD>' + userName + '</TD><TD>' + lastModifiedByDate + '</TD>';
        pageHTMLContent += '</TR>';
        System.debug('pageHTMLContent7 ' + pageHTMLContent);
    }
    pageHTMLContent += '</TABLE></BODY></HTML>';

    return pageHTMLContent;
}
```

}

Please advise an appropriate solution.

Could you please advise how to populate the page with different values depending on the user name who last modified the task record?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here `LastModifiedById` field is not available on objTask record.

So you can do this.

```
controller.addFields(new List<String>{'LastModifiedById'});
objTask = (Task)controller.getRecord();
```

this will fetch the `LastModifiedById` field in task record